# React-router. 404 компонент

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Есть определенный код:

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
    <Route path='/news' component={NewsContainer} />
    <Route path='/profile' component={ProfileContainer} />
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Если перейти на localhost/':abrakadabra', то будет отображаться компонент NotFound, однако, если перейти на localhost/news/:'abrakadabra', то просто не отобразится ничего.

Как правильно отлавливать несуществующий URL?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в Route свойство exact. Благодаря prop-у exact пути сравниваются строго:

path в Route === location.pathname

```
<Route exact path='/news' component={NewsContainer} />
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool